# Crossfilter.js | Declaring dimensions after page load

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

Declaring multiple dimensions in one go is causing a non-responsive error in Firefox. (Pressing "Continue" loads the page, but I can't issue this app to users.) One particular dimension causing the problem. Is there a way to declare it "behind the scenes" after page load? I've tried declaring the dimension in an "onLoad" function but that seems to cause the same error.

**Edit/Update**

The graphic is a co-occurrence matrix with time in years horizontally and a different series vertically (users can pick one of about 16 series, each of which has a dimension created in the code below). The user can also filter to restrict the data showing in the graphic, using `<select>` elements.

Dims is an array storing CF dimensions; ditto CF groups --> grps array; and filters for the dimensions --> dimFilters. All three arrays are same length, same order.

addDropdownItems(0) adds distinct values for each dimension as `<option>` to the filter `<select>` element, if it exists (it does not exist for the two "big" fields).

hideLoader hides a spinning wheel that appears onLoad. optionArray[0] contains the field names. The last two fields are the "biggest" in the sense they have the most distinct values, hence being excluded from being filters - too many `<option>` elements and no user will sensibly want to make such a restrictive filter. However users can still see those two series in the matrix.

```
function loadFunction(){

//many other functions go here

setTimeout(function() {

  for (var k=0; k<optionArray[0].length; k++) {
    if (!dims[optionArray[0][k]]) {
      dims[optionArray[0][k]] = facts.dimension(function(d){ return d[optionArray[0][k]]; });
      grps[optionArray[0][k]] = dims[optionArray[0][k]].group().reduceCount();
      dimFilters[optionArray[0][k]] = [];
    }

  }

  addDropdownItems(0);

  hideLoader();

}, 50);//end timeout
}//end loadFunction
```

Comment: I'd first look at optimizing that one dimension. Are there date conversions involved? because those can be super slow. I think the browser has some particular time limit for any javascript function call. If optimization won't work, you could try putting crossfilter in a webworker e.g. with [crossfilter-async](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter-async) but that's [not an out-of-the-box solution yet](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/602#issuecomment-236296335).

Comment: I suppose another possible solution is to feed in the data incrementally. I'm not sure of the efficiency trade offs. I'd still look at optimizing that one dimension if possible. Some operations in JS are surprisingly slower than others.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. There are no date conversions - it's just a 180MB text file, and this field/dimension has a lot of distinct values. I've (temporarily, I suspect) fixed it by putting the dimension declaration within a SetTimeOut within the onLoad function. Not robust yet though...

Comment: Hmm, yes I suppose that just splitting that dimension into a separate call means you're returning control to the browser sooner / more often. Maybe that is the best approach!

Comment: Any chance you could share the dimension definitions you have and point out which one is taking a long time?

Comment: I did initially declare just the two large dimensions in the set Timeout, but it was unhelpful to the code flow (>2000 lines) to have dimensions declared separately, so now they are all declared in this location at the same time.